# replacing @SequenceGenerator with @GenericGenerator

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

(Hibernate 5, PostgreSQL 9.6, Java 8, Spring ORM 4.3.6)

The following entity class `Car` worked fine:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "carSequence", sequenceName = "car_id_seq", )
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "carSequence")
    private Long id;
    //...
}
```

It is based on the following SQL (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE car (id bigint NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE car ADD CONSTRAINT PK_car PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

However, I got this warning which I wanted to solve:

```
WARN org.hibernate.orm.deprecation: HHH90000014: Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator] sequence-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.
```

So, I replaced the old Car with:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import javax.persistence.*;

@GenericGenerator(
    name = "carSequence",
    strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
    parameters = {
            @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "car_id_seq"),
            @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
            @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "50")
    }
)
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "carSequence")
    private Long id;
    //...
}
```

However, then I got error's in my code:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_car"
   Detail: Key (id)=(-34) already exists.
```

Strange thing: `-34` seems odd.
Other strange thing: sequence generates duplicate keys.

The table of cars is already filled up until `id = 709`.
On the sequence definition, `curval = 15, nextval = 16 and increment = 1`.

Comment: I cleared the table and reset the sequence to 1. Again, it adds a record at id: `-47`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not specifiying the optimizer to use.

In your first variant you're using the SequenceHiLoGenerator, in the second variant you only specify the increment-size without setting the optimizer to HiLo.

According to docs ([SequenceStyleGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/enhanced/SequenceStyleGenerator.html)) Hibernate chooses a generator itself if not specified. Because increment_size is > 1 ([see here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/id/enhanced/OptimizerFactory.java)) Hibernate probably selects the pooled-lo optimizer wich operates differently to seqHiLo.

So, you should add

```
@Parameter(name = "optimizer", value = "hilo"),
```

to your Parameters to set the optimizer explizitly to seqhilo

Comment: i will give it a try